# In Groupon's feeds API, what value should be used for tsToken?

Tags: xml, json, parsing, groupon

I am a new user of [Groupon's feeds API](https://partner-api.groupon.com/feeds).

Here is an example request:

```
https://partner-api.groupon.com/deals.json?tsToken=insert_tracking_token_here&division_id=amarillo&offset=0&limit=100
```

**My question**: What value should be used for **`tsToken`** in place of ***`insert_tracking_token_here`***?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tracking token (e.g. US_AFF_0_987654_123456_0) identifies you as a valid user of their API.

You obtain a tracking token when you [sign up as a Groupon Partner](https://partner.groupon.com/login).

Answer (score 2):

Their help is a mess, but it seems that tsToken contains:

```
{COUNTRY ISO CODE}_AFF_0_{YOUR AFF ID}_212556_0
```

For example: PL_AFF_0_12345_212556_0

The number **212556** is constant, according to https://partner-api.groupon.com/help/deal-api